# $A+B=\prod_{i=1}^kP_i^{\min(a_i,b_i)}$ and $A\cap B=\prod_{i=1}^kP_i^{\max(a_i,b_i)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

**Question:** Prove that $A+B=\Pi_{i=1}^kP_i^{\min(a_i,b_i)}$ and $A\cap B=\Pi_{i=1}^kP_i^{\max(a_i,b_i)}$

**My Thoughts:** In the above question we are assuming that $R$ is a Dedekind domain with field of fractions $F$.  Also, $A=P_1^{a_1}\cdots P_k^{a_k}$ and $B=P_1^{b_1}\cdots P_k^{b_k}$ are nonzero ideals of $R$ with $P_1,\dots,P_k$ distinct primes of $R$. So I suppose that $R$ is a hereditary ring, and so every nonzero ideal is invertible... but I am not quite sure if this is a good strategy to take... any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: I think you mean $A+B=\prod_{i=1}^kP_i^{\min(a_i,b_i)}$ and $A \cap B=\prod_{i=1}^kP_i^{\max(a_i,b_i)}$

Comment: yes, thank you, I fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different characterizations of a Dedekind domain, so if I'm using some result or property you haven't seen let me know. The main slogan here is that, in a Dedekind domain, "to contain is to divide"; ie, if $I$ and $J$ are nonzero ideals, $I$ divides $J$ if and only if $I$ contains $J$.

Now, the case where either $A=R$ or $B=R$ are straightforward (check the details yourself!), so we may assume that there is some $a_i$ non-zero and some $b_j$ non-zero. Likewise, we may assume the $P_i$ are all nonzero.

Now, certainly $P_i^{\min(a_i,b_i)}\supseteq P_i^{a_i}$ and $P_i^{\min(a_i,b_i)}\supseteq P_i^{b_i}$ for each $i$. Hence $A\subseteq\prod_{i=1}^kP_i^{\min(a_i,b_i)}$ and $B\subseteq\prod_{i=1}^kP_i^{\min(a_i,b_i)}$, and so $A+B\subseteq\prod_{i=1}^kP_i^{\min(a_i,b_i)}$. Thus $\prod_{i=1}^kP_i^{\min(a_i,b_i)}$ divides $A+B$, and so – by unique factorization into prime ideals – to show equality we just need to show (a) that no prime ideal of $R$ other than the $P_i$ divides (contains) $A+B$, and (b) that no power of $P_i$ greater than $\min(a_i,b_i)$ divides (contains) $A+B$.

For (a), let $Q$ be a prime ideal such that $A+B\subseteq Q$. Then (eg) $\prod_{i=1}^kP_i^{a_i}\subseteq Q$, and there is some $a_i>0$, and so by definition of prime ideals we have $P_i\subseteq Q$. But "to contain is to divide", and so $Q$ divides $P_i$, and thus by unique factorization of ideals $P_i=Q$. (This is just the fact that Dedekind domains have Krull dimension $1$, if you prefer that language.) Thus the $P_i$ are the only prime ideals containing $A+B$, and hence are the only prime divisors of $A+B$.

For (b), fix some $i$; without loss of generality we may assume $a_i\leqslant b_i$. (The other case is identical.) Now, $A\subseteq P_i^{a_i}$. But also, by unique factorization into primes, we have $A\nsubseteq P_i^{a_i+1}$, or else $P_i^{a_i+1}$ would divide $A$. Clearly this means that $A+B\nsubseteq P_i^{a_i+1}$, and so $P_i^{\min(a_i, b_i)+1}=P_i^{a_i+1}$ does not divide $A+B$.

So, summing everything up, we have that the $P_i$ are the only prime ideal divisors of $A+B$, and that every $P_i$ divides $A+B$ with degree precisely $\min(a_i,b_i)$. By unique factorization of prime ideals this gives us $A+B=\prod_{i=1}^k P_i^{\min(a_i,b_i)}$, as desired. The second problem is very similar; do you think you can see how to do it now?

Comment: Yes!   Thank you so much for the clear and thorough response!

Comment: @User7238 happy it helped! :)